# Get 1 second of samples with audioclip?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was making an music player for a game and i got into problem. Sending a sound packet with full sample of .wav file is too big. Code:

```
float[] samples = new float[clip.samples * 2];
clip.GetData(samples, 0);
int i = 0;

while (i < samples.Length)
{
    samples[i] = samples[i] * 0.5F;
    i++;
}
```

How can i get only 1 second of the AudioClip samples?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
void Start()
 {
         audioSource.time = 13.21f;   // assuming that you already have reference to your AudioSource
         audioSource.Play();
 }

 void Update()
 {
         if(audioSource.time > 14.57f){
                 audioSource.Stop();
         }
 }
```

Comment: I didn't asked to play it. Sending all samples to server is way too much and would cause huge lag.

Answer (score 0):

if you already have samples in an array, a second with 44100hz sampling is .. you guessed it 44100 samples, if you copy those samples to another array - you have just extracted a second. 
Now playing them back is a slightly different matter, as you probably need to dive into OnAudioFilterRead() callback, but you can also use the answer above if that's just the playback you're after